# PHP - Passing form input as a variable to a bash script?

Tags: php, bash, forms

I'm working on a quick and dirty webapp that is designed to wrap common tasks I accomplish with shell scripts into a web interface for a couple of users that cannot use the CLI.

My only issue is passing a value entered into a form to be used as an argument against said shell script.  For example, one bash script simply takes an email address as an argument.  What is the best way to pass this along to my bash script to be executed?

I was thinking of using system() as the PHP show that it could work in this case and then print out the result that the script displays on the webpage but I'm having issues figuring out where to even start.

My form code is mostly placeholder right now and is as follows:

```
  <input type="text" id="syncAcct" runat="server" name="syncAcct" class="form-control" placeholder="user@domain.tld">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" runat="server" name="submit" type="button">Sync Quota</button>
```

I need to take the input from that form (an email address) and pass it to my script (e.g. syncQuota.sh user@domain.tld), if I can somehow print the result from that on the page as well that would be a nice bonus but I'm really working towards basic functionality and am quite lost at this point.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define a `<form>`, set `action` to the PHP page that will process the value from the form.  In PHP, call `system()`.  That function will send the output on the web page.  Call `system()` between `<pre></pre>` tags to get the actual output, without formatting from the browser.  Do not use `exec()` as this one does not send the result back like `system()` does.  Look on the web for tutorials of PHP `<form>` usage.

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice and came up with a snippet of code that does what I'm looking for:

`    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['syncAcct'])) {
        $email = escapeshellarg($_POST['syncAcct']);
        $output = shell_exec("syncQuota.sh $email");
        echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($output) . '</pre>';
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="syncAcct" />
        <button>Sync Quota</button>
    </form>`

Comment: Okay, so the markdown failed me and I cannot edit now but hopefully anyone else stumbling along this can figure it out.  Thanks for your help!